# How is a latent class regression model estimated?

Tags: regression, classification, mixed-model, latent-class

Can someone explain, intuitively, how a latent class regression (LCR) model is estimated (or direct to some digestible explanations)?

I understand how regressions are estimated, no need to comment on it.

For latent class models (LCM), my understanding is that the parameters are actually estimated from counts of the possible combinations of the levels of the variables throughout the data to be used in the model.

But how are these methods actually "mixed" to estimate a LCR? For example if the dependent regression variable is continuous, does the LCR model calculate means of the dependent variable for all possible combinations of the variables to be used in the LCM portion, then somehow simultaneously estimate both models? Are separate regressions estimated for each latent class and what exactly would the independent variables be in this case?

I estimated linear regression model with a continuous dependent variable and categorical effects coded independent variables. This model produced an $R^2$ of ~ 15%.

I then estimated a latent class regression model using the same data (except that the categorical variables were now not effects coded). This model produced an $R^2$ of 87%.

Is the $R^2$ of the LCR unbelievable?

Comment: if you're still here and interested in this question, can you clarify if you actually fit a latent class regression model and got an $R^2$? I'm not familiar with any software that produces an $R^2$ associated with an LCR. LCR models are pretty similar to multinomial regression models, except that the DV is inferred from manifest indicators rather than observed directly; the traditional definition of $R^2$ doesn't apply, and I'm not even sure I've seen many implementations of pseudo-$R^2$ for multinomial logistic models.